# Recursive algorithm for expand/collapse

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures

I'm trying to build out a sort of nested row functionality for my view component. Data can be nested upto any number of levels. Server returns the data in a flat hierarchy. For example, this is what a dataset might look like:

```
[{"name":"A", "Level": 1}, 
{"name":"A.1", "Level": 2}, 
{"name":"A.2", "Level": 2},
{"name":"A.2.1", "Level": 3},
{"name":"A.2.2", "Level": 3},
{"name":"B", "Level": 1}, 
{"name":"B.1", "Level": 2}, 
{"name":"B.2", "Level": 2},
{"name":"B.2.1", "Level": 3},
{"name":"B.3", "Level": 2}]
```

The children of the row go on until another row of the same or numerically lower Level is encountered or we've exhausted the number of rows. For example, the children of A go on until B is encountered i.e. the next row with Level = 1. Similarly, children of A.2(level 2) go on until a numerically lower i.e. level 1 of row B is encountered.

I want to provide a functionality for the user to switch the hierarchy to any level he/she might like to.
So, if user clicks on "Level 1" toggle, the data should show as: 
|A 
|B

Similarly, for level 2, it should show as:
|A
 |A.1
 |A.2
|B
 |B.1
 |B.2
 |B.3

What I've done is, whenever a row is collapsed, I slice the children of that row from the dataset and add them to a children property on that row.
So, if A.2 is collapsed, dataset would look like:

```
[{"name":"A", "Level": 1}, 
{"name":"A.1", "Level": 2}, 
{"name":"A.2", "Level": 2, "children": Array[2]},....so on]
```

User can also expand and collapse a row individually. So, for example, he may have A.2 expanded to show the level 3 rows and then click on "Level 1" toggle. So, this would require me to first collapse the A.2 row to hide its level 3 rows and then collapse the A row to show just level 1 row.

In my implementation, I currently do a multi pass over the array to first collapse it from level 3 to 2 and then 2 to 1. Similarly for expand I do a multi pass from level 1 to 2 and then 2 to 3.
I'm struggling to find a single pass solution for this. This array can get a bit huge so it'd be great if the solution can be constant space as well but it's still fine if you can remove the space constraints and provide a single pass algorithm.

Also, if there's a completely new and more efficient approach, I'd be more than happy to implement it.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why not have the page elements follow the same nesting, so if one element is hidden, its children will consequently be hidden as well?

Comment: I thought of this as well but I need to support this on IE and that's why I'm trying to do as much work as possible in JS. I'd not want to do such kind of thing in HTML.